# Let $X$ be a topological space. Any connected component of $X$ is union of some irreducible components of $X$. How to show this?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I was thinking of writing $C$ any connected component of $X$ as union of the irreducible component of $\{x\}$ where $x$ runs over $C$. But I have doubt that the irreducible component of $X$ containing $\{x\}$ will be contained in $C$  or not. Please help how to proceed?

Answer (score 5):

Let $C$ be a connected component of $X$, and let $x\in C$. Let $F$ be the irreducible component containing $x$. Then $F$ is a connected set containing $x$, and $C$ is the maximal connected set containing $x$, so $F\subseteq C$. (Of course in Hausdorff spaces this is not very interesting, since in that case we have $F=\{x\}$.)